# How to run docker daemon?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run docker daemon using command:

```
docker -d
```

but I receive in console:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d
```

what should I do to run docker daemon?

Comment: Might help you https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/155

Comment: `docker` is the client, not the server (the daemon). The daemon names usually end with `d` (from "daemon", of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-d` flag is used with `docker run` command to run a container in detached mode.

What you're looking for might be [docker-machine start](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/start/) :

```
docker-machine start [arg...]
```

This command starts a machine with one or more machine names as arguments.
For example:

```
$ docker-machine start dev
```

Comment: I edited answer avoiding external content, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 34):

If you stopped the service, you would need the following command to start it again:

```sh
$ sudo service docker start   # for work with SysVinit
$ sudo systemctl start docker # for work with Systemd
```

Also to stopped again, you might use:

```sh
$ sudo service docker stop   # for work with SysVinit
$ sudo systemctl stop docker # for work with Systemd
```

Answer (score 13):

I believe the question is how to run the docker in detached mode and connect back, suppose one has Ubuntu image one can try this

```
sudo docker run -it -d --name myubdocker ubuntu:latest bash
```

It will detach the docker and one can see it running when one tries this

```
sudo docker ps
```

Now how will one attach back to the same docker, thru the following command (CONTAINERID will be listed when one does (docker ps)

```
sudo docker exec -it <CONTAINERID> bash
```

This will give a root command prompt ( can one type exit and again connect back )

Answer (score 12):

I spent several hours trying to figure out why I wasn't able to run Docker containers in my `ArchLinux` environment. The solutions listed above didn't work for me.

Turns out, I had to run the `dockerd` daemon which is a "*persistent process which manages containers*". You can [read more about this here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).

**These commands worked for me:**

1. `$ sudo dockerd`
2. `$ sudo dockerd &`

   - This runs `dockerd` deamon as a background process (more useful)

**These commands didn't work for me:**

1. `$ sudo service docker start` or `$ sudo service docker restart`
2. `$ sudo systemctl start docker`

I hope this helps others who are stuck at a similar problem.

Comment: The correct command must be: sudo service docker start. The last 2 words were reversed.

Comment: I am on Manjaro(Arch-based Linux) and this answer saved me the several hours you spent working on it. +1. Also, this has to be started as a root user, ``sudo dockered`` would be the way to go, but that's understood.

Comment: What command are you supposed to use when you want to stop using docker?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have fixed the typos.

Answer (score 6):

In Manjaro for me worked:

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
$ sudo systemctl enable docker
```

**P.S.**
It should also work for other Linux distributions that use systemd.