# Running docker inside a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-in-docker

I am using the docker dind image and creating a  pod. When I try to run docker build inside the pod, I get an error.

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: dockercontainer
      namespace: default
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker:24.0.0-rc.1-dind
        name: dockercontainer
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
```

The pod is getting created, but when I execute a docker build inside the pod, I get the following error:
`ERROR: Cannot connect to the docker daemon at unix://var/run/docker.sock`

[image]

Comment: I have answered your question. If the answer works, I will mark this question as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232687/how-to-run-docker-daemon/57119910#57119910). Please check and verify.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: this assumes that you're using a docker runtime in K8s! If not, use [kaniko](https://github.com/agavitalis/kaniko-kubernetes).

The docker daemon isn't mounted into the pod - this is the reason for your error. In order to build images, you will need one of these:

- get the docker daemon mounted into each container of the pod
- run the containers in the pod in `privileged` mode

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dockercontainer
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: docker:24.0.0-rc.1-dind
    name: dockercontainer
    securityContext:
      privileged: true # this should do the trick
```

There are some issues w/ building/running containers w/in a K8s pod, **from a security standpoint** (more on this [here](https://kurtmadel.com/posts/native-kubernetes-continuous-delivery/building-container-images-with-kubernetes/) and [here](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)). Much safer approach is to use [sysbox](https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox) but that's perhaps more detailed than we want to get here.

I'm assuming that it's not possible for you to be able to build this image outside of K8s.

Answer (score 2):

I've created the pod with the image you used and didn't face any issue. See the sequence below:

- `docker-pod.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docker
  labels:
    name: docker
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: docker:24.0.0-rc.1-dind
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

- Create the pod:

`kubectl create -f /tmp/docker-pod.yml`

- Wait till it's running, then run `sh` inside it:

`kubectl exec -it docker sh`

- `docker version` shows that docker daemon is running inside it:

```
/ # docker version
Client:
 Version:           24.0.0-rc.1
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.3
 Git commit:        eabb927
 Built:             Thu Apr 27 00:50:17 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.0-rc.1
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.3
  Git commit:       f117aef
  Built:            Thu Apr 27 00:53:29 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.0
  GitCommit:        1fbd70374134b891f97ce19c70b6e50c7b9f4e0d
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.6
  GitCommit:        v1.1.6-0-g0f48801
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

- Note that you don't need to specify

```
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
```

because it's the default user container runs with:

```
/ # whoami
root
```

- you do, however need to run `docker in docker` container in `privileged` mode as its docs instruct.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check the OS Distro? Plz run this command `cat /etc/os-release`. As for the error message, it looks like the docker Daemon isn't running. Can you try running this command `sudo dockerd &`?

You can read more about [dockerd here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/). For ArchLinux, I had posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232687/how-to-run-docker-daemon/57119910#57119910).

Comment: I am trying to run docker inside a container, by pulling the docker dind image, I can't execute sudo command